# WSAEFAULT error when use getsockname function

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2

I have a problem using `getsockname` function. I have this code:

```
struct sockaddr sa;
int sa_len;
sa_len = sizeof(sa);
if (getsockname(socketfd, &sa, &sa_len) != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
   ///
}
else
{
   int error = WSAGetLastError();
   //error here WSAEFAULT always
}
```

As you can see, i always have error when use getsockname function. Error - `WSAEFAULT`. But why? structure and structure size are right, why this happens?

WSAEFAULT desc:

> The name or the namelen parameter is not a valid part of the user
>   address space, or the namelen parameter is too small.

p.s. Application is 64 bit

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `struct sockaddr` is too small to accept the socket address. Either use an appropriately sized struct, such as `struct sockaddr_in`, or better yet, use a `struct sockaddr_storage`, which is guaranteed to be large enough to contain the address. Using a `sockaddr_storage` also allows you to easily support both IPv4 and IPv6 with minimal adjustments.

Edited code:

```
struct sockaddr_storage sa;
int sa_len;
sa_len = sizeof(sa);
if (getsockname(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &sa_len) != SOCKET_ERROR)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how to get port from `sockaddr_storage`? I don't see `sin_port` value

Comment: That's easy. You check `sa->ss_family`, and then cast it to the appropriate type, ie. cast to `struct sockaddr_in` for `AF_INET`, and `struct sockaddr_in6` for `AF_INET6`

Comment: Oh, also, if you want the port for display purposes, you can use `getnameinfo()` to return both the address and the port, all without fiddling with IPv4 and IPv6 specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of general *struct sockaddr* use the one specified for your protocol i.e. *struct sockaddr_in* for IPv4 address. See [here](http://www.ccplusplus.com/2011/09/getsockname-example-c.html) for a complete example.